# HTML5 Local Storage Error

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am trying to check if it is the first time the user has been to my application. So I check if count in local storage is null, if it is then the user is a new user. However, the code below stops at str_count = localStorage.getItem("count"); no line after this will run. What is wrong here? If the user is new there will be no "count" in local storage but it should just return null not crash.

```
var count = 0;
str_count = localStorage.getItem("count");
if (str_count == null || str_count == "null")
{
    //do something
} 
else 
{
    count = parseInt(str_count);
            count++;
            localStorage.setItem("count", count);

}
```

}

Comment: which browser is this failing in? Not all versions of all browsers support localStorage

Comment: Works fine in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/brantolsen/ZYmKZ/.

Comment: This code is to handle the case where the user is using IE. I am using a HTML5 database for other browsers.

Comment: I have an application that uses HTML client side database storage, but this won't work in IE so I am trying to find another solution using local storage.

Comment: Check out store.js (https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the browser support localStorage - you could check the feature before you try to get the value:

```
var str_count = 0;
if (window.localStorage) {
    str_count = localStorage.getItem('count');
}
```